# projective closure of smooth affine curve defined by Weierstrass equation is still smooth?

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

In general, projective closure of smooth affine curve is not always smooth projective curve.

But, what about projective closure of smooth affine curve defined by Weierstrass equation?

Let $E$ be a **smooth** affine curve （over field $K$） defined by $y^2 +a_1 xy+ a_3y  =x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_4x + a_6$（all coefficients are in $K$）, then is the projective closure of $E$ is always smooth projective curve?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, just compute the partial derivatives on the affine piece where e.g., $Y = 1$.